# Forum and section moderation

Tags: 7, nodes

I need to import a Simple Machine Forum 2.0.3 into Drupal Forum, and my client need to have the possibility to moderate section in the new forum. He want to assign 1+ moderator for section.

Is this possibile in drupal forum (with some modules) ?

Thanks.

M.

Comment: Hello @ZioBudda, did you find any solution to your problem? I am using the Advanced Forum, and planing to install Forum Access which gives the ability to assign a moderator to each forum or container. But I find it a little bit overload.

Comment: Nope, I have not found any solution. I will try Advanced Forum with Forum Access. Hope....

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I posted a similar question [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74348/restrict-forum-access-based-on-user-user-list). You may want to look at the answers. Forum Access provides an option to assign moderators to forums and forum containers. I have also installed this module only to use this functionality. Although I think that's a bit overkill but at the moment does the job (I am still on testing).